# Object doesn't support property or method remove

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9, extjs4.1

I am using extjs and trying to remove a dom element dynamically like this-

```
if (Ext.getElementById('a'))
    Ext.getElementById('a').remove();
```

This works fine in Chrome. I am running application on IE9 as well but it throws the error- Object doesn't support property or method remove

Please let me know if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.getElementById()` is a private method - you may want to consider using `Ext.get()` instead.

Anyhow, if it works in Chrome and not in IE, most likely your dom is invalid - search for missing closing tags, or alternatively validate your dom using an online validator. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860757/prototype-element-remove-not-working-in-ie).

Comment: Yes. 
    document.getElementById() 

was the problem. As well does extjs have something similar to this-                              document.getElementsByClassName() ??

Comment: Well. There can be many elements with the same class. You should look at [Ext.Element.down()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-down).